# How to avoid NG0100 when Child component emits event to Parent at ngOnInit?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm facing an NG0100 issue illustrated by the following StackBlitz example: [StackBlitz NG0100](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khw9xr?file=src/app/parent/parent.component.html).

*Open the StackBlitz Console to see the error.*

#### The context

- A child component (*ChildComponent*) exposes an *init* EventEmitter triggered at *ngOnInit*.
- A parent component (*ParentComponent*) subscribes to the child component *init* event, in which the it simulates an API call, changing the binded value *loading*.

#### Observation

In *parent.component.html*

```html
<p>Parent Works!</p>

<!-- COMMENTING THE BINDING BELOW AVOIDS NG0100 -->
loading binding 1: {{ loading }}
<app-child (init)="onChildInit($event)"></app-child>
<!-- BUT THIS SAME BINDING NEVER TRIGGERS NG0100 -->
loading binding 2: {{ loading }}
```

It appears that when Angular loads the parent template:

1. Angular gets the *loading* value of binding 1: value is *false*.
2. Angular initializes the child component, calls *ChildComponent.ngOnInit*, emits *init* event which changes the *loading* value of the parent to *true*, raising the NG0100 error.
3. Angular gets the *loading* value of binding 2: value is always *true* at that time (no problem).

#### Requirements

I have 2 requirements:

1. For graphical reasons, I need the binding 1.
2. I really need the child component to emit the *init* event once it has been initialized for the first time (*ngOnInit* or other) for initiating the data loading in the parent, because the child component sends some data (illustrated by the *Math.random()*) that I can't access another way.

Any **nice** solution would be appreciated...

I have just added my real use case based on PrimeNG Table [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tabledoc-demo-qmz1yx?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: Having event emissions on init is not a good pratice. What you could do instead is do something through the ngAftercontentInit from the parent. 
Also, avoid async methods on the component level.

Comment: You can always access data from the child using @ViewChild

Comment: Thanks @CaioOliveira for your suggestions. In fact I'm using the PrimeNG Table component (from [here](https://primeng.org/table)) which has a "lazyLoadOnInit" boolean property which automatically emits onLazyLoad event at ngOnInit, when set to true. Therefore I'm not responsible for emitting this event at ngOnInit.

Comment: Concerning the @ViewChild, I can't really use it because the data I need is not immediately accessible from the **Table** component (here named **ChildComponent**). The data I need is only available as parameter of the **onLazyLoad** event.

Comment: You can use BehaviorSubject variable for that. you need to publish value from child and subscribe it on parent.